# How can I create a template class that contains various number of objects of different classes from the same class template

Tags: c++

Assume we have a class template like this:

```
template <int n>
class Item{...}
```

Maybe it is

```
template <int n>
class Item
{
    int numbers[n];
}
```

I wonder if I can build a class template like this:

```
template <int n>
class Array{...}
```

An object of `Array<n>` should contains n members. One of them is an `Item<1>` object, another is an `Item<2>` object... and the last one is an `Item<n>` object.
And the `Array` should contains item itself rather than a point to the item.

I think maybe I can define `Array` in a recursive way:

```
template <int n>
class Array
{
    Item<n> lastItem;
    Array<n-1> others; 
}
```

But it seems lost a recursive base that `Array<0>` should contains nothing.

Comment: You need a specialization for `Array<0>` (or perhaps `Array<1>`) to break the recursion. Have you tried that?

Comment: why the website does not show "<n>" in the text...

Comment: Or you can make a tuple of `Item<i>`. Look up `std::integer_sequence`.

Comment: @那温度 Because you need to surround it in ` to format as code.

Comment: if you have code with a compiler error please include a [mcve] and the compiler error in the question. If you don't, its time to write it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need a specialization for `Array<0>` to break the recursion.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <int n>
struct Item
{
    int numbers[n];
};

template <int n>
struct Array {
    Item <n> item;
    Array<n-1> other;
};

template <>
struct Array<0> {};
```

Note, that retrieval of the `Item<n-1>, Item<n-2>` instances is a bit awkward:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Array<3> array;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(array.item), Item<3>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(array.other.item), Item<2>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(array.other.other.item), Item<1>>);
   
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Code example](https://godbolt.org/z/b8Kxqqjc8)

As an alternative, you could use inheritence together with a free function template `get_item` to retrieve the other items:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <int n>
struct Item
{
    int numbers[n];
};

template <int n>
struct Array : Array<n-1> {   // <---- inheritence instead of composition
    Item <n> item;
};

template <>
struct Array<0> {};

template <int n, int m>
Item<n> get_item(Array<m>& arr) {
    static_assert(0 < n && n <= m);
    return static_cast<Array<n>&>(arr).item;
}


int main()
{
    Array<3> array;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(array.item), Item<3>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(get_item<3>(array)), Item<3>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(get_item<2>(array)), Item<2>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(get_item<1>(array)), Item<1>>);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live code example](https://godbolt.org/z/h7fPbo89T)

Comment: Ah I missed that. In that case the specialization of `Array<0>` can be replaced with a specialization of `Array<1>`. Or the specialization of `Array<0>` can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::index_sequence` and `std::tuple`:

```
template <typename Seq> class ArrayImpl;

template <std::size_t... Is>
class ArrayImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    std::tuple<Item<1 + Is...>> data;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using Array = ArrayImpl<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

With regular usage of `std::tuple`, so, something like:

```
Array<42> arr;
std::get<0>(arr.data); // item<1>

std::apply([&]<std::size_t... Is>(Item<Is>&... items) { /*..*/ }, arr.data);
```